# JSF components as selectors for css styles

Tags: html, css, jsf

Choosing a component as a `selector` in a css file is quite simple.
The pattern is

`selector {
   attribute: value;
   ...
}`

I could choose say `<p>` as a selector as an HTML tag but how does it work with JSF tags?

I found out that you can use HTML equivalents of JSF tags, e.g. 
 `h:inputText` to `<input>` ... but that is just about the only JSF-HTML conversion I know ... :)
 
Where can I find all corresponding tags?

Are there any other methods of styling JSF components with css?

Comment: I've been reading about JSF in detail since 2 tweeks or so. Before that I did more backend-technologies, so thank you for your overview :)

Answer (score 1):

Every (or most) **UIComponent** in the JSF library has an attribute to set CSS styling for your personal use: `styleClass` which in the back will set the CSS `class` attribute for the resulting HTML code so here's an example:

```
<h:outputText value="here is my text"
              styleClass="some-class" />
```

Now in your CSS:

```
.some-class{
  color: red;
}
```

This is how  you would proceed to add styling to JSF UIComponents.